# Why IE cannot close tab on "Cancel" button click c#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I have this cancel button:

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Cancel" />
```

I want click that button it will close the current window, so in codebehind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string jScript = "<script>window.close();</script>";
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "keyClientBlock", jScript);
       // Response.Write("<script>parent.close_window();</script>");
    }
```

But I do not see that window tab close in my IE browser. Is there anything can be corrected here?

Comment: try using window.top.close();

Comment: window.close() will only work if window.open(..) has been used, so I would suggest to also try window.open('','_self').close();

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this server side when you can just attach to the buttons click event in js/jQuery?

This probably wont work due to a browser security setting unless the window itself was spawned via the `window.open()` method, so you'll want to use a workaround if this is absolutely necessary.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#button').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          window.open('','_self').close();
     });
</script>

<button id="button" value="close" />
```

Comment: Sorry, I implement the button like you said but it will not appear properly. And click on it also not close the tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
function CloseWindow() {
window.open('','_self').close();
}
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string jScript = "<script>CloseWindow();</script>";
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "keyClientBlock", jScript);
}
```

I would also suggest to create a function in javascript and then just call it with your code, and if your not going to do anything in the .cs side us DGibs answer.

Comment: What you mean from : "in the .cs side us..."

Comment: Code Behind is the .cs side, the function above will be a javascript found on the aspx side or the UI, and the Button1_Click is the .cs side or Code Behind